# Cant decode data send over sockets between C# and Python

Tags: c#, python, sockets, networking, network-programming

I have been having a bit of trouble getting some test softare up and running correctly. At the moment all I am trying to do is send a message using C# to a Python server and then for the server to resend this message back to the C# client.

I have been able to send strings from python but when I try and send a string contained in a variable the C# client only picks up a blank space. I have got this working correctly using a Python client which leads me to believe my problem is to do with encoding and decoding but I have tried as many combinations as I can think of and it doesn't seem to work.

[image: Python Server Code]

[image: C# Send Data]

[image: C# Receive and Display Data]

Comment: Please include the actual code and not screenshots

Comment: Well.. You are Encoding to ASCII in Python before sending it across the wire. Shouldn't you then also be Decoding ASCII in C# instead of Encoding once more?

Comment: I have uploaded my client C# code at https://pastebin.com/qz3qQHx3 and my python server code at https://pastebin.com/nFdfdiCg. Thanks.